# Creating zip file in windows phone 8

Tags: mobile, windows-phone-8, zip

How i can create Zip files in windows phone 8. Is there any Open source SDK available for doing the same in windows phone 8. In my application i need to send zipped PDF file to dropbox. I do find some solution for windows phone 7 but they don't have any support for WP8.

Comment: Hey i dont know what is wrong with the question, I can point out similar 10000 questions in stackoverflow. It seems like moderators are doing a bad work here.

Comment: Now a days the SO users are showing their effort to close the question. Not to give answers.